# does divide order and the index of a subgroup the order of the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

does divide order and the index of a subgroup the order of the
group?

for example if $G$ be a non abelian group and $H$ be a abelian subgroup of $G$ and $H \not\subseteq Z(G)$ . does divide order $[H :Z(G) \cap H]$ of order $G$?

if is true, why?

Comment: Before a  group order problem, I see a word order problem ...

Answer (score 2):

Lagrange's theorem says
$$
|G| = (G:H)\, |H|
$$
For $K \subseteq H \subseteq G$, this gives
$$
|G| = (G:H) (H:K) \, |K|
$$

Answer (score 1):

Whenever $A$ is a subgroup of $B$ and $B$ is a subgroup of $C$, the index $[B:A]$ is a divisor of $|C|$. This is simply so because the order of a subgroup is always a divisor of the order of the larger group. Your question is about the specific case $A=Z(G)\cap H$, $B=H$, $C=G$.